# Can docker host ping its containers?

Tags: networking, docker, port, ping, host

I'm running docker on mac, my docker is running centos and ifconfig shows eth0 address is "172.17.0.2".

I tried to ping this 172.17.0.2 in my terminal but failed. So except using "docker run" command, is there a way to access to container by it's services like sshd?

I searched internet and found port mapping, so I added "-P" option to run it:

```
docker run -itP centos6.5 bash
```

It should assign a random port mapping right? But the list command doesn't show any "port" information, like below(have scroll a bit)

```
docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
136ab365eddd        centos6.8_dev       "bash"              11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds                           practical_wilson
```

This is weird: why port mapping doesn't work? I tried tcping:

```
$tcping localhost 5000
localhost port 5000 closed.
```

Comment: you should be able to ping, you can get container ip by running `docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' your_container`. -P assigns random ports to ports that are marked as exposed in your image so will not do anything as ping uses different protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can docker host ping its containers?

no.

not on Mac, at least.

and on linux, it only works incidentally and is not something you should do anyways.

[Docker isn't a virtual machine](https://derickbailey.com/2016/08/29/so-youre-saying-docker-isnt-a-virtual-machine/) and shouldn't be treated like it is. You should be thinking of it as a virtual application, instead.

if you need to get into the service via tcp/ip port, you need to map the port number from the container.

`docker run -p 1234:1234 my-image`

where `1234` is the tcp/ip port.

this creates a service listening at `localhost:1234` on your host machine.